# Create template suggestion for item-list.html.twig

Tags: 8, theming

I have to change the markup and I have to add CSS classes to `themes/classy/templates/dataset/item-list.html.twig`. But only for a specific `item-list.html.twig` in a specific block.

How do I create a preprocess function, which create a template suggestion for this `item-list.html.twig`? So I am able to use e.g. `item-list-facets.html.twig`?

Comment: You have been asking this already in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227668/overwrite-twig-template-files-from-a-contrib-module-in-my-custom-subtheme/227757?noredirect=1#comment278756_227757, and I don't know how to help you more without just writing down the code for you. You need to inspect the data structures you get and then do something conditionally based on that. Or, as I suggested already over there, request a more specific theme (suggestion) from the module developers

Answer (score 4):

I think it's better to use hook__theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter:

Something like this:

```
 /**
 * Implements hook__theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_item_list_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {
  $suggestions[] = 'item_list__' . str_replace('-','_',$variables["attributes"]["id"]);
}
```

Just make sure that in your suggestions name you use _ instead of -, otherwise you will get suggestions in the debug, but Drupal won't use it.

Answer (score -1):

If its a class you might not need to have a separate twig file, but can simply add a class in your preprocess.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_item_list($variables) {
  // conditional class
  $variables['custom-class'] = _some_function_to_return_class();
}
```

Copy the `item-list.html.twig` to your custom theme folder, and use the class.

Comment: But then this class is added to ALL `item-list.html.twig` files in my subtheme? I want to create a separate `item-list.html.twig` file e.g. `item-list-facets.html.twig`. Or can I do it with twig, inside my custom theme's `item-list.html.twig` ?

Comment: _some_function_to_return_class(); should be responsible to provide unique class based on field name etc. you can do it either way, with tem-list-facets.html.twig or item-list.html.twig.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry can you provide me with an example? I don't understand. What do you mean with `_some_function_to_return_class();` How do I wright the function to return class?

Comment: in `<li class="facet-item">` I have to add a custom class, so I have e.g. `<li class="facet-item custom-class">`. How do I have to do this?